# XSD Namespace Not Appearing in JAXB Marshalled XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

When I marshall a XML from my JAXB generated XSD/Schema classes, the root node is missing the xmlns:xsi information, see below.  Any ideas on how to get the namespace information in my marshalled XML?

**Current Marshall Result:**

```
<exampleType>
```

**Desired Marshall Result:**

```
<exampleType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../schemas/example.xsd">
```

**My Schema (sample part of it):**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0.1">
        <xs:element name="project" type="exampleType">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../schemas/example.xsd"
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
```

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` schema location attribute appear in the marshalled XML you need to set it on the `Marshaller` using the `JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION` property.

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "../schemas/example.xsd");
```